# Sound mostly not working in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've recently gotten back into playing Skyrim, but I'm having some trouble.

Namely, sounds are almost completely non-existent. Occasionally when attacking, or usually when speaking, all the sound comes back and starts working just fine (including background music and stuff), but for the most part it's completely silent. As a Khajiit playing stealth, this makes things quite difficult!

I'm not sure what information may be useful. I'm on pretty much a completely fresh install of Windows 8 (just upgraded yesterday) but the sound was glitchy before the upgrade too, so I don't think that's particularly useful...

Any advice on what to try would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is quite a weird one, but could be helpful to others!

Basically, the headphones I'm using (Turtle Beach PX22) seems to have some kind of "minimum input volume" requirement, otherwise it gets filtered out as background noise. The solution was to set my computer's volume to 100%, and use the in-line amp to adjust volume instead. Now the headphones receive the full audio input and handle it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely related to your sound card drivers. After some searching the web i found that downloading the DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer the problem was fixed. You can download the software [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35) of the official microsoft website. This problem has been reported after upgrading your game in OS. (from vista to win7 and from win 7 to win 8). This solution fixed most problems. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try after work today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Ok, try changing your audio quality. You can do that from: Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Select your sound device > Properties > Advanced. Then change your quality level to 16 bit, 48000 Hz. [SOURCE](http://www.overclock.net/t/1173196/no-sound-when-i-play-skyrim)

Comment: It's already set to that.